# Creating object of the class with paint method

Tags: java

I created a menu with some options to choose. One of those options is "Play with computer" which starts the game.

```
        JButton ai = new JButton("Play with computer");
    ai.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            GameBoard play = new GameBoard();
            hi.dispose(); //jframe
        }
    });
```

And then comes GameBoard:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class GameBoard extends Canvas {
    private Image dbi;
    private Graphics db;
    private JFrame okno;
    Rectangle aiPaddle = new Rectangle(10, 590, 10, 50);
    Rectangle pPaddle = new Rectangle(10, 100, 10, 50);
    Rectangle ball = new Rectangle(560, 10, 10, 10);
    Player p = new Player(this);
    Ai a = new Ai(this);
    Ball b = new Ball(this);
    GameBoard() {
        okno = new JFrame();
        okno.setTitle("Pink Ponk");
        okno.setSize(600, 300);
        okno.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.black);
        okno.setResizable(false);
        okno.setVisible(true);
        okno.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        addKeyListener(p);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GameBoard gra = new GameBoard();
        gra.okno.add(gra);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Graphics g) {
        dbi = createImage(10, 50);
        db = dbi.getGraphics();
        paint(db);
        g.clearRect(0, 0, 600, 300);
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.drawRect(p.getX(), p.getY(), 10, 50);
        g.fillRect(p.getX(), p.getY(), 10, 50);
        g.drawOval(b.getX(), b.getY(), 10, 10);
        g.fillOval(b.getX(), b.getY(), 10, 10);
        g.drawRect(a.getX(), a.getY(), 10, 50);
        g.fillRect(a.getX(), a.getY(), 10, 50);
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        pPaddle = new Rectangle(p.getX(), p.getY(), 10, 50);
        aiPaddle = new Rectangle(a.getX(), a.getY(), 10, 50);
        ball = new Rectangle(b.getX(), b.getY(), 10, 10);
        g.clearRect(0, 0, 600, 300);
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.drawRect(p.getX(), p.getY(), 10, 50);
        g.fillRect(p.getX(), p.getY(), 10, 50);
        g.drawOval(b.getX(), b.getY(), 10, 10);
        g.fillOval(b.getX(), b.getY(), 10, 10);
        g.drawRect(a.getX(), a.getY(), 10, 50);
        g.fillRect(a.getX(), a.getY(), 10, 50);
    }

}
```

I'm sure it should work, but it does not. I'm getting black screen, without any rectangles or ovals. Threads from other classes are working, because I'm still losing the game. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GameBoard constructor, which is the only thing you call when your start button is pressed, creates a new frame, sets its background, and makes it visible. But it doens't add any component to the frame. You probably need to add

```
okno.add(this);
```

Note that it's not really the responsibility of the constructor of your Canvas to display a frame and add itself to this frame, though. I would move the frame creation outside of the constructor. Let the constructor do what it's supposed to do: construct the object.

Comment: One more question: what's the best place to create frame?

Comment: In the action listener: it's its responsibility to create a frame containing the canvas. You may of course delegate that to a private method, and call this private method from the action listener.